# Will Muslims have to worship Allah in Jannah?

Tags: jannah

All Muslims must have to offer prayer five times a day and they are responsible for this in front of Allah.

So, my question is that, will Muslims be required to offer prayers in the heaven as well?

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly understood that Paradise is is the place of reward, not a place of obligations, so there will surely be no obligation to pray there.

**Tasbeeh and Zikr**:

> Muslim narrated in his Saheeh from Jaabir ibn ‘Abd-Allaah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be
>   upon him) said: “The people of Paradise will eat and drink therein,
>   but they will not blow their noses or defecate or urinate. Their food
>   there will turn into burps and sweat like musk. They will be caused to
>   recite tasbeeh and praise, as they are caused to breathe.”

الله اعلم